# some portion of jquery in running remaining is not working in code but works in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on edit username with hide/show text field and, I found some questions for 'js works in console but not in code' but I have different scenario. some part jquery run perfectly, but rest of code is not working in code, it works in console, please help me with that. (I have loaded jquery that's why some code works)
on edit click
**Here are the images for buttons**
[fisrt for edit name](https://prnt.sc/1395f9e)

[second for close edit button which is not working](https://prnt.sc/1395e0o)

```js
//for edit field showing
$(document).on('click', '.edit-nickname', (element) => {
  element.preventDefault();

  $('.hide-on-cancel').show();
  $('.show-on-cancel').hide();

});
//for hiding edit field and display  username 
$(document).on('click', '.cancel-nickname', (element) => {
  element.preventDefault();
  // alert('hii');
  $('.hide-on-cancel').hide();
  $('.show-on-cancel').show();
//(OPTIONAL CODE to ABOVE) IF I UNCOMMENT BELOW 3 LINE THAT WORKS BUT 4th and 5th LINE IS NOT WORKING 

  // $('#sd-close').addClass('d-none');
  // $('#sd-check').addClass('d-none');
  // $('#sd-edit').addClass('d-none');

  // $('#sd-pen').removeAttr('style');
  // $('#text-edit-nickname').removeAttr('style');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="edit-nickname" class="second-text1">
  <div class="row" style="padding-left: 50px;width: 90%;margin: auto;">
    <span class="show-on-cancel" id="text-edit-nickname" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ \Auth::user()->nickname}}">
                {{ucfirst(\Auth::user()->nickname)}}
                </span>
    <span class="form-group  nickname-form-group cust-d-none hide-on-cancel" id="sd-edit">
                <input id="new_nickname" class="form-control" style="height: 44px;margin-top: 20px;" name="nickname"   type="text" value="{{ \Auth::user()->nickname}}" >
                <input id="old_nickname" class="" type="hidden" value="{{ \Auth::user()->nickname}}" >
            </span>
    <span class="edit-nickname">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil ml-4 show-on-cancel" id="sd-pen"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-check ml-2  save-nickname cust-d-none hide-on-cancel" id="sd-check"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-times cust-d-none cancel-nickname hide-on-cancel" id="sd-close"></i> 
            </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Were are you loading the script?

Comment: @Keith  script loaded and other functionality works perfectly

Comment: Hi , this is happening because your first event handler `edit-nickname` is referring whole `span` so when you click on `cancel` both event are getting trigger that's why fields are still visible . Instead be more specific i.e : change `$(document).on('click', '.edit-nickname', (element) => {` to `$(document).on('click', '#sd-pen', ..`

Comment: @Swati for edit it works, but now working when I click close icon button (and yeah i also tried your sloution but still not working)

Comment: Working fine have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vwz5gq48/)

Comment: @Swati , yes its working but only on console not in code

Comment: @Swati yes now it is working i changed both click event from to ID now worked thanks for your solution, I really appreciate it!!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

First put your script tag at the end of your body tag.
Then add `document.ready` function to your code like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $(document).on('click', '.edit-nickname', (element) => {
        element.preventDefault();

        $('.hide-on-cancel').show();
        $('.show-on-cancel').hide();

    });
   //for hiding edit field and display  username 
   $(document).on('click', '.cancel-nickname', (element) =>{
        element.preventDefault();
        // alert('hii');
        $('.hide-on-cancel').hide();
        $('.show-on-cancel').show();
//(OPTIONAL CODE to ABOVE) IF I UNCOMMENT BELOW 3 LINE THAT WORKS BUT 4th and 5th LINE IS NOT WORKING 


        // $('#sd-close').addClass('d-none');
        // $('#sd-check').addClass('d-none');
        // $('#sd-edit').addClass('d-none');

        // $('#sd-pen').removeAttr('style');
        // $('#text-edit-nickname').removeAttr('style');
    });
});
```

Comment: OP is using delegate listener, so that will not be the problem.

Comment: @connexo Dude, first of all this is best practice second the main problem is with the script tag.

Comment: @shahabvshahabi , I have ready function, and edit text field also showing when I click edit button but when I click close button , it is not workig